# Using JsonWriter with dynamic class list

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I currently have a list builder from a separate class:

```
public class psuedoMe {
    public string relName { get; set; }
    public List<string> lstName { get; set; }
}
```

I have a function that populates this, but then writes it to `Json` using `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter`:

```
private static string returnJson(List<psuedoMe> sentList)
{
    StringBuilder jsonSB = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter jsonSW = new StringWriter(jsonSB);
    using (JsonWriter jsonWrite = new JsonTextWriter(jsonSW))
    {
        jsonWrite.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (psuedoMe sentItem in sentList)
        {
            jsonWrite.WriteStartObject();
            foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propInfo in sentItem.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                jsonWrite.WritePropertyName(propInfo.Name);
                jsonWrite.WriteValue(propInfo.GetValue(sentItem, null));
            }
            jsonWrite.WriteEndObject();
        }
        jsonWrite.WriteEndArray();
    }
    return jsonSB.ToString();
}
```

However I am receiving an error when it tries to write the `public List<string> lstName` into `jsonSB`. I've tried excluding only the `lstName` from the `JsonWriter` however this only then loops through the list and doesn't write it to the `jsonSB` at the end.

Is there anyway of using the above `returnJson` to write to the list of `strings`?

There error I get is: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriterException: Unsupported type: System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String].`

Comment: `foreach (psuedoMe sentItem in sentList)` will take string item on each iteration, and `foreach(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propInfo in sentItem.GetType().GetProperties())` will iterate thru properties of `String` type, as a result you're creating `JSON` with `String` type's property names, and property values, is it what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: @michael moore, that's exactly it. It needs to create a JSON with their property names and values. Which then can be processed in Angular (further down the line however).

Comment: Is there anything stopping you just using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sentList)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of `JSON.NET` you're using? Here's the [source code of `JsonWriter` class's `WriteValue` method](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/Default/Project/Json.NET/3.5-Release-6/Release/netcf-2.0/Newtonsoft.Json.Compact/Newtonsoft.Json.Net20/JsonWriter.cs?ImageName=Newtonsoft.Json.Compact)

```
public virtual void WriteValue(object value)
    {
      if (value == null)
      {
        WriteNull();
        return;
      }
      else if (value is IConvertible)
      {
        IConvertible convertible = value as IConvertible;

        switch (convertible.GetTypeCode())
        {
          case TypeCode.String:
            WriteValue(convertible.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            return;
          case TypeCode.Char:
            WriteValue(convertible.ToChar(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            return;
          case TypeCode.Boolean:
            WriteValue(convertible.ToBoolean(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            return;
          case TypeCode.SByte:
            WriteValue(convertible.ToSByte(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            return;
          case TypeCode.Int16:
            WriteValue(convertible.ToInt16(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            return;
          case TypeCode.UInt16:
            WriteValue(convertible.ToUInt16(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            return;
          case TypeCode.Int32:
            WriteValue(convertible.ToInt32(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            return;
          case TypeCode.Byte:
            WriteValue(convertible.ToByte(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            return;
          case TypeCode.UInt32:
            WriteValue(convertible.ToUInt32(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            return;
          case TypeCode.Int64:
            WriteValue(convertible.ToInt64(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            return;
          case TypeCode.UInt64:
            WriteValue(convertible.ToUInt64(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            return;
          case TypeCode.Single:
            WriteValue(convertible.ToSingle(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            return;
          case TypeCode.Double:
            WriteValue(convertible.ToDouble(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            return;
          case TypeCode.DateTime:
            WriteValue(convertible.ToDateTime(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            return;
          case TypeCode.Decimal:
            WriteValue(convertible.ToDecimal(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            return;
          case TypeCode.DBNull:
            WriteNull();
            return;
        }
      }
#if !PocketPC && !NET20
      else if (value is DateTimeOffset)
      {
        WriteValue((DateTimeOffset)value);
        return;
      }
#endif
      else if (value is byte[])
      {
        WriteValue((byte[])value);
        return;
      }

      throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported type: {0}. Use the JsonSerializer class to get the object's JSON representation.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, value.GetType()));
    }
```

As you can see, it doesn't have support for `List<T>`. So for `List<T>` it will throw  `Unsupported type exception`, and even in exception message it is suggesting to use `JsonSerializer` to get object's JSON representation.